# NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined installing fandjango on Python3

Tags: python, django, fandjango

I am trying to install fandjango by using:

```
pip install fandjango
```

However I get the error:

```
Collecting fandjango
  Using cached fandjango-4.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Apaar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0j7g1eqn\fandjango\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        execfile('fandjango/version.py')
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Apaar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0j7g1eqn\fandjango\
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fandjango only supports Python2 according to its [Pypi entry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fandjango/4.2.1), and you are using Python3 (Python3 does not have the `execfile` builtin function).

Comment: I think your only options are: (1) find another package that does what fandjango does (2) Use python 2 instead of python 3 (3) Contribute to the fandjango project by [helping them upgrade their code](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango/issues/113)