# Error trying to Install sheetsync using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to currently install a library called syncsheets but am receiving the following error. I have looked around similar situations having similar issues and arrived at one conclusion but am still having a hard time understanding my current situation. Ref Question: [NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined installing fandjango on Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525178/nameerror-name-execfile-is-not-defined-installing-fandjango-on-python3)

I am under the impression this library only supports python2, any help/confirmation would really be appreciated on how I can work around this error. Thank you!

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ip2brw81/sheetsync/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ip2brw81/sheetsync/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-tyozokps
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ip2brw81/sheetsync/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ip2brw81/sheetsync/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        execfile(os.path.join('sheetsync','version.py'))
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The package  works only with Python 2.7. The only workaround is to fork [sources](https://github.com/mbrenig/SheetSync/) and update them to work with Python 3 but that means a lot of hard work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library that I think you're trying to install, [`sheetsync`](https://pypi.org/project/sheetsync/) is only compatible with `python2`. In your question you are attempting to install with `python3`.